# Concatenate text results from two different tables in snowflake

Tags: sql, concatenation, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a source table that has a unique `source_id`/`source_timestamp`, and a not unique `product_id`. From two target tables, I want to aggregate all the `text` fields, for each respective `product_id` from the target tables that were recorded prior to each `source_timestamp`. So the final output should be a table grouped by `source_id`

raw `source_table`

| source_id | source_timestamp | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 | p1 |
| s2 | 2023-01-12 00:00:00 | p1 |
| s3 | 2023-01-04 00:00:00 | p2 |
| s4 | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | p2 |

raw `target_table1`

| id | product_id | text_timestamp | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | p1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | "jan 1st text" |
| t2 | p1 | 2023-01-19 00:00:00 | "jan 19th text" |
| t3 | p2 | 2023-01-05 00:00:00 | "jan 5th text" |
| t4 | p2 | 2023-01-21 00:00:00 | "jan 21st text" |

raw `target_table2`

| id | product_id | text_timestamp | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | p1 | 2023-01-06 00:00:00 | "jan 6th text" |
| t2 | p1 | 2023-01-10 00:00:00 | "jan 10th text" |
| t3 | p2 | 2023-01-12 00:00:00 | "jan 12th text" |
| t4 | p2 | 2023-01-02 00:00:00 | "jan 2nd text" |

desired output

| source_id | product_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| s1 | p1 | null |
| s2 | p1 | "jan 1st text jan 6th text jan 10th text" |
| s3 | p2 | "jan 2nd text" |
| s4 | p2 | "jan 2nd text jan 5th text" |

the query I have now looks something like this:

```
with main_cte as (
select id,
  timestamp
  product_id
from source_table
),
cte1 as (
select
 st.id,
 st.timestamp,
 LISTAGG(tt1.text, ' ') within group (ORDER BY st.timestamp) as text
from source_table st
 left join target_table1 tt1 on tt1.product_id = st.product_id
     and tt1.timestamp < st.timestamp
group by 1,2
),
cte2 as (
select
 st.id,
 st.timestamp,
 LISTAGG(tt2.text, ' ') within group (ORDER BY st.timestamp) as text
from source_table
 left join target_table2 tt2 on tt2.product_id = st.product_id
    and tt2.timestamp < st.timestamp
group by 1,2
)
```

and the final output should be

```
select st.id,
 (cte1.text || cte2.text) as aggregated_text
from source_table
 left join cte1 on cte1.id = source_table.id
 left join cte2 on cte2.id = source_table.id
```

where `aggregated_text` in the final select statement concatenates the text from both CTEs, but is sorted in order of the source_table timestamp.

Comment: Hi - it would be a lot easier if you showed your source tables, sample data for them, the result you are trying to achieve and the logic being applied to achieve that result. While showing the SQL you’ve attempted is always helpful, as your CTEs are not valid SQL it’s not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: Added more detail and reference to the raw source tables. hopefully this helps

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
with target_data as (
    select id, product_id , text_timestamp  , text_val
    from target_table1
    union
    select id, product_id , text_timestamp  , text_val
    from target_table2
)
select s.source_id
,s.product_id
,listagg(t.text_val, ' ') within group (order by t.text_timestamp)
from source_table s
left outer join target_data t on s.product_id = t.product_id and t.text_timestamp < s.source_timestamp
group by s.source_id, s.product_id
order by s.source_id, s.product_id
;
```